# PHP Cookie store user form searches - multiple searches stored

Tags: php, cookies, cookiestore

I am trying to store user searches in a cookie to show the users "Recent Searches".  The form contains 2 params:

1. Keyword
2. Location

I can create the cookie no problem, but I can not update it and store more than 1 search.  Indeed.co.uk they store the searches in the Cookie in the below format:

```
"q=carpenter&l=london&ts=1506177856392:q=bricklayer&l=Southwark&ts=1506008036065:q=labourer&l=Southwark&ts=1506007988029"
```

As you can see Indeed store multiple UNIQUE searches.

I am using PHP does anyone know how to replicte how Indeed store the user form searches?  I need to bring the queries as an Array.

Thanks

John

UPDATE - Code Tried:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["RS"])) {

    // Get cookie value
    $new = "key=$keyword&loc=$locationKey:";
    //"q=carpenter&l=london&ts=1506177856392:q=bricklayer&l=Southwark&ts=1506008036065:q=labourer&l=Southwark&ts=1506007988029"
    $prev_value = $_COOKIE["RS"];

    $prev_value = stripslashes($prev_value);
    $prev_value = json_decode($prev_value, true);
    // Add current value to array and set cookie again

    $prev_value = $prev_value."".$new;

    $new_value = json_encode($prev_value, true);

    setcookie('RS', $new_value, time()+3600);

}else {

    // Set cookie to current value
    $init_value = "key=$keyword&loc=$locationKey:";
    $init_value = json_encode($init_value, true);
    setcookie('RS', $init_value, time()+3600);

}
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Mr Pro Pop - Updated Question with code tried

Comment: So, what you are trying to do is save multiple values?

Comment: Yes spot on, I want to save all unique form searches for job site, so I can display "My Recent Searchs"

Comment: Zaaayymn bro! I was writing the code but another answer was first. Anyway, indeed separates them with a colon. Plus what Jimmmy said.

Answer (score 0):

To store more searches into one cookie, first you have to read actual value from the cookie, then add new search.

something like this:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "searches";
$stored_searches = isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ? $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] : null;

$new_search_value = "keyword:asdf&location=http://example.com";

if($stored_searches){

    $searches = explode('|',$stored_searches);

    $searches[] = $new_search_value;

    $searches_to_store = implode('|', $searches);

} else {
    $searches_to_store = $new_search_value;
}


setcookie($cookie_name, $searches_to_store, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

this code checks whether there exists your cookie and if so, parses all searches into array. Then adds new search and implode into cookie string.
Searches are delimited by | (pipe) character
Then saves it..

I would however suggest to save those data about searches into session values, its stored on server and can't be manipulated by user

```
$_SESSION['searches'] = $searches_to_store;
```

**EDIT:**
to store only unique searches, can assign stored searches into array by some key.

for example like this:

```
//after explode
$searches_by_key = array();
foreach($searches as $search){
     list($keyword, $location) = explode('&', $search);
     $searches_by_key[$keyword] = $search;
}
```

by this you will have unique keys in $searches_by_key, that you can store into cookie

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Jimmy, thanks for this, it does work!  My only issue now is to stop Replicated form searches been added to the cookie and only store unique keyword+loc combinations

Comment: i edited the answer to contain hint on unique searches